# Why does the content disappears sometimes from visulizer

Tags: vtk, point-cloud-library

In my visualizer class based on QVTKWidget  and pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer the entire contents disappears sometimes. Then, when rotating the (invisible) clouds with the mouse, the content is visible again.

Any idea why this happens?

**EDIT**
Seems, I'm not the only one experiencing that problem. There is a question on PCL forum: http://www.pcl-users.org/pcl-visualization-PCLVisualizer-Almost-all-points-disappear-td4023738.html Unfortunately without an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause:**

This problem is caused while visualizing a large cloud.

**Solution:**

My observation is that when I remove extreme points that are relative far away, it works back to normal.

Comment: @withniu: Thanks, it makes sense! Unfortunatelly i've stopped working on that project, and can't verify it soon. But as I remember, this happened as I merged several clouds together. It never happened with original single clouds. Good to know for future projects :-)

Comment: @ROX: If you have searched for the answer of that problem during many nights, you would know, that this is a fairly good answer. The main reason, I've stopped working on the project is the bad documentation of PCL.